# Get different values with same id in javascript

Tags: javascript

**Html**

```
<c:forEach var="legList" items="${legList}">/* iterating over ledger name and 
                                                  ledger id */                  
   <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="hidden" class="legid" name="legid" id=legid
        value=${legList.ledgerId}>
        <a onclick=display(document.getElementById('legid').value)
        href='#myModal' role="button" data-toggle="modal">${legList.ledgerName}</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

**Javascript**

```
var display = function(id){
alert(id);  //want to get id of clicked ledger name
}
```

But here problem is I'm getting same id on clicking all links and I know why it is happening because we can not get values with same id. so my question is how I can get different Id's here when id is changing inside for loop.Hope I am clear with my question.

Comment: Why not assigning each link unique id like `id=${legList.ledgerId}` and display it like `<a onclick=display(document.getElementById(${legList.ledgerId}).value)
href='#myModal' role="button" data-toggle="modal">${legList.ledgerName}</a>` ?

Comment: It worked. Thank u so much

Answer (score 2):

`id`s **must** be unique in the document. If you break that rule by having multiple elements with the same `id`, the results are officially undefined (although in practice browsers give you the first one when you use `getElementById`).

Instead, use the fact that your `a` element instance is available as `this` within the `onclick`, and use that to find the `input` next to it with the DOM (perhaps using [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling) in this case):

```html
<a onclick="display(this.previousElementSibling.value)" ...
```

Example:

```js
function display(value) {
  alert("value is: " + value);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="hidden" class="legid" name="legid" value="value1">
      <a onclick=display(this.previousElementSibling.value)
      href='#myModal' role="button" data-toggle="modal">Value 1</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="hidden" class="legid" name="legid" value="value2">
      <a onclick=display(this.previousElementSibling.value)
      href='#myModal' role="button" data-toggle="modal">Value 2</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="hidden" class="legid" name="legid" value="value3">
      <a onclick=display(this.previousElementSibling.value)
      href='#myModal' role="button" data-toggle="modal">Value 3</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

In general, I'd suggest not using `onclick`, but instead using modern event handling or one of the many popular MVC-style frameworks instead.